# How does compiler understand Unicode characters so quickly?

Tags: unicode, compiler-construction, ascii

I have made a document based program lately. 
But what intrigues me that how can a compiler(in my case, objective-c) convert any character into Unicode so fast while these characters are only visual presentations.

I think maybe A~Z and all other common characters can be converted from ASCII to Unicode very easily. What about other special character such as brand icon and copyright icon?

I am solely interested in the internal working of such conversion.

Example:
How do compiler understand what "©" is in a blink of second? Is it by looking up a UNICODE table? But if I have 1000000 "©", does my compiler look them up in the table 1000000 times? That is very time consuming, isn't it?

Comment: It's not easy to understand what you're having trouble trying to understand. What do you think the compiler needs to convert to what? Why do you think A is easier than copyright icon?

Comment: Please add a concrete example, I have no idea either what you're asking about.

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.3.0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't see "©". It sees whatever numerical representation of "©" occurs in the source file it's processing. No lookup is needed, because it's already in the form the compiler uses. (Some conversions might be needed if, for example, the source file is in UTF-8 and the compiler uses UTF-32 internally, but such conversions don't require a full Unicode table.)

Comment: In addition, it's perfectly possible to create *invalid* Unicode characters. The compiler will not complain; all that happens is that you get garbage when you attempt to output your malformed strings. (And what the *output* looks like, depends only on your terminal/console and its settings.)